# Kendo UI Grid - issue creating data-id row attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm working on a `Asp.Net MVC 5 Web Pages` project, where one of the partial views generates an Html table. It of course mixes the Razor syntax in with Html.

Now I need to implement this table as a `Kendo UI Grid`, where the HTML table is used as the `DataSource` (see this as a reference - http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/from-table).

Great so far - and yes, my new Kendo grid does in fact render nicely.

ex/

[image]

Only problem is that the Kendo Grid now seems to be overwriting the `<tr>` `data-id` attributes I'm injecting into each row.

So how would I turn this into a Kendo `rowTemplate` ?

**Before implementing the Kendo Grid**, here is the Html table as rendered:

```html
<table id="summary-table" class="table table-hover table-extra-condensed">
 <tr data-id="80" data-nodes="2008-08-08" data-title="EUREX IRS" data-subtitle="All">
  <td class="hidden">80</td>
  <td><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> EUREX IRS</td>
  <td class="text-right">USD</td>
 </tr>
 <tr data-id="50" data-nodes="2008-08-08" data-title="EUREX IRS" data-subtitle="IRS-EUR">
  <td class="hidden">50</td>
  <td><span class="indent">IRS-EUR</span></td>
  <td class="text-right">USD</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the new table, now rendered as a Kendo grid (Kendo added `data-uid` but I lost my custom 'data-' row attribs):

```html
<table id="summary-grid" class="table table-hover table-extra-condensed" data-role="grid" role="grid">
<tr data-uid="fcc1ffab-f1e7-4ea4-9b79-7c4149bbbfa3" role="row">
  <td style="display:none" role="gridcell">80</td>
  <td role="gridcell"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> EUREX IRS</td>
  <td role="gridcell">USD</td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

Here's the partial.cshtml file snippet:

```js
@model IEnumerable<WhatifSummaryViewModel>

@{
    string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}

<table id="summary-grid" class="table table-hover table-extra-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id" hidden class="hidden">Id</th>
            <th data-field="product">@Settings.Whatif.SummaryPortfolioName1 - @Settings.Whatif.SummaryPortfolioName2</th>
            <th data-field="currency" class="text-right">Currency</th>
            <th data-field="margin" class="text-right">@Settings.Whatif.SummaryCurrentExposureName</th>
            <th data-field="wi" class="text-right hidden-xs">What-If</th>
            <th data-field="impact" class="text-right">Impact</th>
            <th data-field="chart" class="text-center hidden-xs">View</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); ++i)
        {
            string title;

            if (Model.ElementAt(i).SubTitle.Equals("ALL", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                title = "<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i> " + Model.ElementAt(i).Title;
            }
            else
            {
                title = "<span class='indent'>" + Model.ElementAt(i).SubTitle + "</span>";
            }            
            <tr data-id="@Model.ElementAt(i).PortfolioId" data-nodes="@String.Join(",", Model.ElementAt(i).NodeDates)" data-title="@Model.ElementAt(i).Title" data-subtitle="@Model.ElementAt(i).SubTitle">
                <td class="hidden">@Model.ElementAt(i).PortfolioId</td>
                <td>@Html.Raw(title)</td>
                <td class="text-right">@Model.ElementAt(i).Currency</td>
                <td class="text-right">@String.Format("{0:#,0}", Model.ElementAt(i).Utilisation)</td>
                <td class="text-right hidden-xs">@(Model.ElementAt(i).WhatIfRun ? String.Format("{0:#,0}", Model.ElementAt(i).WhatifExposure) : "")</td>
                <td class="text-right">@(Model.ElementAt(i).WhatIfRun ? String.Format("{0:#,0}", Model.ElementAt(i).ImpactToExposure) : "")</td>
                <td class="text-center actions hidden-xs"><a href="#" onclick="SU.showChart('@i');return false;"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i></a></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and finally, the Kendo grid which is configured in my `onReady` javascript function:
(NOTE: the `rowTemplate` below is commented, and certainly does cause a scripting error if uncommented).

```js
// Kendo UI grid 
$("#summary-grid").kendoGrid({
 resizable: true,
 toolbar: ["pdf","excel"],
 columns: [
  { field: "PortfolioId", hidden: true },
  { field: "title"},
  { field: "Currency", title: "Currency" },
  { field: "Utilisation", title: "Margin" },
  { field: "WhatifExposure", title: "What-if"},
  { field: "ImpactToExposure", title: "Impact" },
  { field: "Chart", title: "View" }
 ] 
 @*rowTemplate: '<tr data-uid="#= uid #" data-id="#= @Model.ElementAt(i).PortfolioId #" data-title="#= #" >'*@
});
```

In the end, I'd like to add my custom `data-` row attribs. I was thinking that the kendo `template` would work, but I can't figure it out in this `Web Pages Razor` context.

Help is appreciated...

Bob

Comment: Clearly there is a disconnect in understanding here with both the partial.cshtml and the template in the script code that appear to both try to insert rows. Here is an example of placing attributes via script in the databound event handler...http://www.telerik.com/forums/set-data-title-attribute-to-every-td-cell  I don't think the "grid from table" example you link to really even is what you are attempting to do here.

Comment: @Mark, The get from table is exactly what I am doing, and it works. The databound event might be the answer. Thank you. But ultimately, I will attempt to convert the project to angular with kendo UI.